# Closing the excel file I opened when there are multiple excel files opened in the same instance with the Window_Closed event (C#)?

Tags: c#, excel

In my program, I open an excel file to read it and then when the program is closed I want to close the excel file that I opened. I'm using C#.

I succeded doing that but onlyy if there are no other excel files opne together. I tried using the Window_Closed event with this lines of code :

```
    private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks xlBooks = xlApp.Workbooks;

        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook in xlBooks)
        {
            if (xlWorkbook.FullName == Properties.Settings.Default.ExcelFilePath)
            {
                xlWorkbook.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

If there are no other excel files than the one I created, the list xlBooks contains the excel file that I opened. But if there is one excel file that is already opened, than the list xlBooks contains only that excel and do not conaint the excel file that I opened with the program. This way I cannot close the excel file that I opened if there are others excel files already opened (which is something that might happen).

What I used to open the excel file was :

```
    public Application excel { get; set; }
    public Workbook wkb { get; set; }

            excel = new Application();
            wkb = excel.Workbooks.Open(Properties.Settings.Default.ExcelFilePath, 0, FileAccess.Read);
```

Comment: I see, you can use ``your`` Excel App instance if foreach (excel.Workbook xlWorkbook in xlBooks)
        {
            if (xlWorkbook.FullName == Properties.Settings.Default.ExcelFilePath)
            {
                xlWorkbook.Close();
            }
        }